# Overlap CSS button on p element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a button on top of and floated to the right of a `<p>` element.

Here is my attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZBZZU/

HTML

```
<p id="hello"><strong>Hello</strong></p>
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

CSS

```
#hello {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    border:solid 2px;
    border-color:black;
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
    margin:2px;
}

#button {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: are u trying to put the button on top of the red container, or on top of hello word but still inside the red container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the button a child of the p element and then position it absolutely

**HTML**

```
<p id="hello">
    <strong>Hello</strong>
    <button id="button">Button</button>
</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#hello {
    position: relative;
}

#button {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how I could create the child element?

Comment: Just put it inside the `<p>` tags as I did above

Comment: @user2066880 Don't forget to mark the best answer as 'accepted' to let the community know your issue was resolved

Comment: I'm running into a small problem.  I need the button to line up with the parent element (since the parent element will not always be in the same place).  Right now, using absolute, it always stays in the same place on the page.

Comment: Did you add `position:relative;` to `#hello` as I used in my answer?

Comment: Ahh didn't see that.  Ok I think I how all of this works now.  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need `position: absolute`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/ZBZZU/1/

```
#button {
    display:inline;
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    right: 15px;
}
```

Seconmd option:

Put the button in the `<p>` tag

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/ZBZZU/2/

Comment: Your first solution won't work if the `p` position were to change. The second one makes the text in `p` not be completely centered

Comment: It is centered if you use my original styling with my second option. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/ZBZZU/3/

Comment: Yes, but you didn't suggest that while that is the solution I presented in the first place.